# Data query not working

Tags: sql

I'm creating a query in stack exchange's data explorer to look at the best new users on physics stack exchange. I haven't coded in SQL much at all, and so I apologize if this is an especially dumb question.

My code is

```
SELECT
    CreationDate,
    Id,
    AccountId,
    Reputation
FROM 
    USERS
WHERE 
    Reputation > 200
    AND CreationDate BETWEEN 2016-1-1 00:00:00 AND 2016-12-31 24:00:00
ORDER BY 
    Reputation
```

And when I run it, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '00'

I am unsure what the problem is. I've already looked around a bit, but I couldn't find anything relevant to the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing single quotes around the dates and there is no hour 24

```
SELECT CreationDate,Id,AccountId,Reputation 
 FROM  USERS 
 WHERE Reputation>200 AND CreationDate >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND CreationDate <'2017-01-01 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY Reputation
```

Comment: Without quotes on the dates, it's going to try to do do arithmetic `2016-1-1 = 2014` then break when it encounters the times.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, thank you for the edit and explanation. =)

Comment: @heather It's always the small things